# Ruby Enumerable#find returning mapped value

Tags: ruby

**Does Ruby's `Enumerable` offer a better way to do the following?**

```
output = things
  .find { |thing| thing.expensive_transform.meets_condition? }
  .expensive_transform
```

[`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is great for finding an element in an enumerable, but returns the original element, not the return value of the block, so any work done is lost.

Of course there are ugly ways of accomplishing this...

#### Side effects

```
def constly_find(things)
  output = nil

  things.each do |thing|
    expensive_thing = thing.expensive_transform
    if expensive_thing.meets_condition?
      output = expensive_thing
      break
    end
  end

  output
end
```

#### Returning from a block

*This is the alternative I'm trying to refactor*

```
def costly_find(things)
  things.each do |thing|
    expensive_thing = thing.expensive_transform

    return expensive_thing if expensive_thing.meets_condition?
  end

  nil
end
```

#### `each.lazy.map.find`

```
def costly_find(things)
  things
    .each
    .lazy
    .map(&:expensive_transform)
    .find(&:meets_condition?)
end
```

Is there something better?

Comment: I would solve the problem within `thing` by memoizing the result of `expensive_transform`.

Comment: assuming `expensive_transform` is reliable and consistent isn't there a pattern that could be applied to `thing` to determine the the potential result of `expensive_transform` without actually applying it? Obviously we have no idea what `expensive_transform` does. Additionally you could create a mutable object that memoizes `expensive_transform` as @Stefan mentioned and then `thing` would already know this value without the need to process twice but this requires performing the operation on 1 to n elements where n is the found element or the end of the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course there are ugly ways of accomplishing this...

If you had a cheap operation, you'd just use:

```
collection.map(&:operation).find(&:condition?)
```

To make Ruby call `operation` only "on a as-needed basis" (as the documentation says), you can simply prepend [`lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy):

```
collection.lazy.map(&:operation).find(&:condition?)
```

I don't think this is ugly at all—quite the contrary— it looks elegant to me.

---

Applied to your code:

```
def costly_find(things)
  things.lazy.map(&:expensive_transform).find(&:meets_condition?)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to create an enumerator that generates values `thing.expensive_transform` and then make that the receiver for `find` with `meets_condition?` in `find`'s block. For one, I like the way that reads.

**Code**

```
def costly_find(things)
  Enumerator.new { |y| things.each { |thing| y << thing.expensive_transform } }.
             find(&:meets_condition?)
end
```

**Example**

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
  def expensive_transform
    self.class.new(value*2)
  end
  def meets_condition?
    value == 12
  end
end

things = [1,3,6,4].map { |n| Thing.new(n) }
  #=> [#<Thing:0x00000001e90b78 @value=1>, #<Thing:0x00000001e90b28 @value=3>,
  #    #<Thing:0x00000001e90ad8 @value=6>, #<Thing:0x00000001e90ab0 @value=4>]
costly_find(things)
  #=> #<Thing:0x00000001e8a3b8 @value=12>
```

In the example I have assumed that `expensive_things` and `things` are instances of the same class, but if that is not the case the code would need to be modified in the obvious way.

Comment: Custom enumerators are highly underrated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "obvious best general solution" for your problem, which is also simple to use. You have two procedures involved (`expensive_transform` and `meets_condition?`), and you also would need - if this were a library method to use - as a third parameter the value to return, if no transformed element meets the condition. You return nil in this case, but in a general solution, `expensive_transform` might also yield nil, and only the caller knows what unique value would indicate that the condition as not been met.

Hence, a possible solution within Enumerable would have the signature

```
class Enumerable

  def find_transformed(default_return_value, transform_proc, condition_proc)
     ...
  end

end
```

or something similar, so this is not particularily elegant either.

You could do it with a single block, if you agree to merge the semantics of the two procedures into one: You have only one procedure, which calculates the transformed value and tests it. If the test succeeds, it returns the transformed value, and if it fails, it returns the default value:

```
class Enumerable

  def find_by(default_value, &block)
    result = default_value
    each do |element|
      result = block.call(element)
      break if result != default_value
    end
  end

  result

end
```

You would use it in your case like this:

```
my_collection.find_by(nil) do |el|
  transformed_value = expensive_transform(el)
  meets_condition?(transformed_value) ? transformed_value : nil
end
```

I'm not sure whether this is really intuitive to use...